# MySQL appears to be using only one CPU core

Tags: mysql

I am running a query on a table that has over 5 million rows and this query takes about 30 minutes to run. For obvious reasons this is unacceptable, and I have rewritten the query to perform in under 10 seconds. But my underlying problem is that the query is only using around 12.5% cpu and appears to not be using the full resources of the server. The server has 8 cores and only appears to be using 1 when running the query 100%/8 cores = 12.5% CPU per core. The database uses the MyISAM engine if that matters.

I understand that in most circumstances you don't want your server bogged down by 1 query, but in this case it is acceptable (the query is running on a testing server that is not accessible to the real world so traffic and other running services are not a problem).

Long story short, Is it possible to give a single query access to more than 1 CPU or because of MySQL architecture is it impossible to thread(at the CPU level) a single query? I guess there is also a third option that it is just a coincidence that the query is only using 12.5 cpu and MySQL can use multiple cores per query.

Comment: In your case it may simply be that the problem isn't really CPU related but disk access related.

Comment: More suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: How do I move it to SuperUser?

Comment: Check this for your answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15185

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Currently one SQL statement runs from start to end in the same 
physical thread."

http://lists.mysql.com/internals/37329